# Z-Index not working over table elements

Tags: css, tooltip, z-index

I have tried a lot but unable to figure out whats wrong. The z-index is not working at all when hovering over the **Available Balance** ***question mark (?)***. Upon hover over the question mark ***(?)***, it can be noticed that the tooltip is getting cut by the table heading area. Can someone please guide me what needs to be changed? Here is the complete code I am working with. Sorry for the long code but I have tried to put in as much as I can for some one to figure this out.

```css
/* SECONDARY TOOLTIP (S) */
[tooltip] {
 position: relative;
}

/* Arrow */
[tooltip]:before {
 width: 16px;
 height: 6px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: 1px;
 top: calc(100% - 10px);
 opacity: 1;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 10;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #00204e;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 pointer-events: none;
}

/* Text */
[tooltip]:after {
 transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: 11px;
 top: calc(100% - 10px);
 opacity: 1;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-shadow: none;
 background: #00204e;
 border-radius: 4px;
 color: #fff;
 content: attr(tooltip);
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 white-space: normal;
 width: max-content;
 font-size: 9px;
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
 line-height: normal;
 max-width: 150px;
 text-align: left;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.71, 1.7, 0.77, 1.24);
 pointer-events: none;
 /* overflow: overlay; */
 z-index: 999999;
}

[tooltip]:hover:before,
[tooltip]:hover:after {
 opacity: 1;
 pointer-events: auto;
 top: calc(100% + 0px);
 z-index: 99999;
 overflow: visible;
 position: absolute;
}
/* SECONDARY TOOLTIP (E) */


.claro .dojoxGridHeader:first-child .dojoxGridRowTable {
    border-left-width: 0;
}
.claro .dojoxGridMasterHeader .dojoxGridRowTable {
    border-left: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.base .dojoxGridRowTable {
    height: 30px !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
table.dojoxGridRowTable {
    table-layout: auto;
}
.dojoxGridHeader table {
    text-align: center;
}
.dojoxGrid table {
    padding: 0;
}
.dojoxGridRowTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 0;
    empty-cells: show;
}
table {
    font-size: 100%;
}

table[Attributes Style] {
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
    -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
}
user agent stylesheet
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}

.claro .dojoxGridHeader:first-child {
    /* margin-left: -50px; */
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px -1px;
}
.dojoxGridHeader {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}

.base .dojoxGrid {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #00204e;
    padding: 0px 1px 20px 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    /* margin-top: 115px; */
    /* border-top: solid 1px #D0D0D0; */
    /* border-bottom: solid 1px #D0D0D0; */
    /* margin-bottom: 20px; */
    width: 100%;
    /* width: 647px; */
    /* height: 226px !important; */
}
.base .dojoxGrid {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.base .dojoxGrid {
    font-size: 0.916em;
}
.dojoxGrid {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EBEADB;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-outline-style: none;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

.portlet {
    margin: 4px 0 30px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

body {
    /* font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; */
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #00204c;
    /* margin-left: 125px; */
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
.base .dojoxGridRowTable {
    height: 30px !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.dojoxGridHeader table {
    text-align: center;
}
.dojoxGridRowTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 0;
    empty-cells: show;
}
table {
    font-size: 100%;
}


table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}

.claro .dojoxGridHeader:first-child {
    /* margin-left: -50px; */
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px -1px;
}

.dojoxGridHeader {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}

.base .dojoxGrid {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #00204e;
    padding: 0px 1px 20px 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    /* margin-top: 115px; */
    /* border-top: solid 1px #D0D0D0; */
    /* border-bottom: solid 1px #D0D0D0; */
    /* margin-bottom: 20px; */
    width: 100%;
    /* width: 647px; */
    /* height: 226px !important; */
}
.base .dojoxGrid {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.base .dojoxGrid {
    font-size: 0.916em;
}
.dojoxGrid {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EBEADB;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-outline-style: none;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

.claro .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridRowTable tr {
    background: none;
}
.claro .dojoxGridRowTable tr {
    background: url(images/row_back.png) #fff repeat-x;
}

tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}

.base .dojoxGridRowTable {
    height: 30px !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.dojoxGridHeader table {
    text-align: center;
}
.dojoxGridRowTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 0;
    empty-cells: show;
}
table {
    font-size: 100%;
}

table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}

.claro .dojoxGridHeader:first-child {
    /* margin-left: -50px; */
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px -1px;
}
.dojoxGridHeader {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}

.base .dojoxGrid {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #00204e;
    padding: 0px 1px 20px 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    /* margin-top: 115px; */
    /* border-top: solid 1px #D0D0D0; */
    /* border-bottom: solid 1px #D0D0D0; */
    /* margin-bottom: 20px; */
    width: 100%;
    /* width: 647px; */
    /* height: 226px !important; */
}
.base .dojoxGrid {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.base .dojoxGrid {
    font-size: 0.916em;
}
.dojoxGrid {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EBEADB;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-outline-style: none;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

#AccountSummarySavingsListPortlet th[idx="3"], #AccountSummarySavingsListPortlet td[idx="3"] {
    text-align: right !important;
}
.claro .dojoxGridHeader tr:first-child .dojoxGridCell {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
.base .dojoxGridHeader th.dojoxGridCell {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00204e;
    border-bottom: thin;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #D0D0D0;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left !important;
    /* white-space: nowrap !important; */
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
.base .dojoxGridHeader th.dojoxGridCell {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #7692B7;
}
.base .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    padding: 5px;
}
.base .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
.base .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    text-align: center;
}
.claro .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.claro .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    background: url(images/header.png) #e5edf4 repeat-x top;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #BCBCBC #BCBCBC #BCBCBC transparent;
}
.base .dojoxGrid th {
    text-align: center;
}
.base .dojoxGridCell {
    border: none;
    /* padding-left: 0px; */
}
.base .dojoxGridCell {
    border: none;
    /* padding-left: 0px; */
}
.base .dojoxGridCell {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-left: 3px !important;
}
.claro .dojoxGridCell, .claro .dojoxGridCellFocus {
    outline: none;
}
.claro .dojoxGridCell {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-color: transparent #E5DAC8 #E5DAC8 transparent;
}
.claro .dojoxGridCell {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}



.base .dojoxGridHeader th.dojoxGridCell {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00204e;
    border-bottom: thin;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #D0D0D0;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left !important;
    /* white-space: nowrap !important; */
    padding: 15px 0px;
}
.base .dojoxGridHeader th.dojoxGridCell {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #7692B7;
}
.base .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    padding: 5px;
}
.base .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}
.base .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    text-align: center;
}
.claro .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid #BCBCBC;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.claro .dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    background: url(images/header.png) #e5edf4 repeat-x top;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #BCBCBC #BCBCBC #BCBCBC transparent;
}
.base .dojoxGrid th {
    text-align: center;
}
.base .dojoxGridCell {
    border: none;
    /* padding-left: 0px; */
}
.base .dojoxGridCell {
    border: none;
    /* padding-left: 0px; */
}
.base .dojoxGridCell {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding-left: 3px !important;
}
.claro .dojoxGridCell, .claro .dojoxGridCellFocus {
    outline: none;
}
.claro .dojoxGridCell {
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border-color: transparent #E5DAC8 #E5DAC8 transparent;
}
.claro .dojoxGridCell {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.dojoxGridHeader .dojoxGridCell {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #F6F4EB #ACA899 #ACA899 #F6F4EB;
    background: url(images/grid_dx_gradient.gif) #E8E1CF top repeat-x;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.dojoxGridCell {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #EBEADB;
    border-right-color: #D5CDB5;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
caption, th {
    text-align: left;
}
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, th, var {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
body, div, dl, dt, dd, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
    /* margin: 0; */
    padding: 0;
}


th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: -internal-center;
}


table {
    font-size: 100%;
}

/*------------------------------------------ */

table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}

#A_12 {
  border: 1px solid #00204e;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table class="dojoxGridRowTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 1001px;" id="TABLE_1"><tbody id="TBODY_2"><tr id="TR_3"><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="TH_4" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem  dojoxGridCellFocus" idx="0" style="text-align: center;text-align: center;width:30%;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid1522757357169402654"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode" id="DIV_5">Account</div></th><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="TH_6" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem" idx="1" style="text-align: center;text-align: center;width:5%;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid1522757357169402654"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode" id="DIV_7">Currency</div></th><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="TH_8" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem" idx="2" style="text-align: right;text-align: center;width:12%;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid1522757357169402654"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode" id="DIV_9">Pending balance</div></th><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="TH_10" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem" idx="3" style="text-align: right;text-align: center;width:12%;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid1522757357169402654"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode" id="DIV_11">Available balance</div><a tooltip="this is a test" style="
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    /* overflow: visible; */
" id="A_12">?</a>
</th><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="TH_13" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem" idx="4" style="text-align: center;text-align: center;width:12%;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid1522757357169402654"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode" id="DIV_14">Accrued Interest Rate</div></th><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="TH_15" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem" idx="5" style="text-align: center;text-align: center;width:10%;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid1522757357169402654"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode" id="DIV_16">Active</div></th><th tabindex="-1" aria-readonly="true" role="columnheader" id="TH_17" class="dojoxGridCell dojoDndItem " idx="6" style="text-align: center;text-align: center;width:12%;" dndtype="gridColumn_grid1522757357169402654"><div class="dojoxGridSortNode" id="DIV_18">Interest Rate</div></th></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Do you know about `Stacking-Context`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: remove overlow:hidden from `.dojoxGridCell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because overflow is hidden in class .dojoxGridCell

set overflow to inherit

```
.dojoxGridCell {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #EBEADB;
    border-right-color: #D5CDB5;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: inherit;
}
```